# Apply creditmemo to an invoice php devkit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I need to be able to apply a credit memo to an invoice using the php devkit, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Using Intuit Anywhere/Intuit Partner Platform, or using qbXML/Web Connector?

Comment: I'm using IPP to integrate with Quickbooks.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually possible... Intuit's docs don't mention anything about doing this. I would wait a few days to see if Intuit responds with an XML example (if they can give you XML, I can give you the corresponding PHP code for it) and then submit a support ticket to them asking for an XML example of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate the credit memo to a customer or job.

You can’t see the link between invoice and creditmemo in IDS V2. Based on the IDS V3 spec (http://developer.intuit.com/fmsv3spec/index.html), it looks like the linkedtxn will be available when it comes out and hopefully that will show the link.

IPP is not showing the link between CreditMemo – Invoice.

You can pull all the CreditMemos - http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/CreditMemo but they do not show the linked transaction back to the invoice like payment does.

You can see if the credit memo has been paid/used or if the creditmemo status is Payable it means the creditmemo is still available.

See also https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=86&threadid=18156

Comment: Thanks. That's the conclusion I came to as well. I guess I'm stuck waiting until IDS V3 shows it's face.

Comment: sadly all the links are now 404ing. i'm curious if there's an answer now that v3 is out.

Comment: These were all referring to QuickBooks Desktop. The QB API for desktop is being discontinued. To access QB Desktop data, you would need to use the QBXML SDK to access.